# Typescript linting error, cannot find namespace error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to setup a .ts file with dummy data, I get the error 'Cannot find namespace 'TrackPlayer'', any ideas?

```ts
import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';

export const tracks: TrackPlayer.Track[] = [
  {
    id: '1',
    url: 'https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/The-Epic-Hero-Epic-Cinematic-Keys-of-Moon-Music.mp3',
    title: 'Keys of moon',
    artist: 'The Epic Hero',
    artwork: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1003/200/300',
    album: '',
    duration: 149,
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    url: 'https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Raindrops-on-window-sill.mp3',
    title: 'Raindrops on window sill',
    artist: '',
    artwork: 'https://picsum.photos/id/10/200/300',
    album: 'Chosic',
    duration: 119,
  },...
```

https://react-native-track-player.js.org/

Comment: Do your `react-native-track-player` has the `export default` keyword? otherwise you will need to destructure the type, like: `import { TrackPlayer }from 'react-native-track-player';`

Comment: TrackPlayer["Track"][]

Comment: @TachibanaShin `TrackPlayer.Track` does exactly the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at type definitions on Github [index.ts](https://github.com/doublesymmetry/react-native-track-player/blob/main/src/index.ts):

```
import * as TrackPlayer from './trackPlayer';

export * from './constants';
export * from './hooks';
export * from './interfaces';

export default TrackPlayer;
```

If you import using [Default import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#default_import) syntax: `import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';`

- you are only importing the default export
- the default export happens to be a constant - created via [Namespace import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#namespace_import)

Meanwhile, you need to access `Track` exported by `export * from './interfaces';`

You can achieve it using:

```ts
import * as TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';

export const tracks: TrackPlayer.Track[] = [];
```

Alternatively, use [Named import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#named_import):

```ts
import { Track } from 'react-native-track-player';

export const tracks: Track[] = [];
```